# Numerical key nested collection

Tags: mongodb

How would I go about querying nested collections that have numerical keys?

I can select one specific collection when I know the key, but what if I don't? Is there some kine of a "mask/pattern"? I'm new to mongodb, so I'm still struggling.

Collection example:.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598842f22605c6cb8de9db78"),
    "17" : {
        "name" : "some name 1",
    },
    "18" : {
        "name" : "some name 2",
    },
    "19" : {
        "name" : "some name 3",
    }
},
{ ... }
```

What I was able to do (select when I know numerical key):

```
db.getCollection('my.collection').find({'17.name' : 'some name 1'});
```

So far my search was fruitless, can anyone at least point me into the right direction?
What I would expect:

```
 db.getCollection('my.collection').find({'#.name' : 'some name 1'}); <-- return every record from collection that has specified name and any numerical key
```

Answer (score 0):

CrazySabbath, in this case, you have nested **documents**, not nested collections. A MongoDB document can nest other documents, which is an embedded document.

Using the mongo shell, you can make a query directly using the collection name, like (without the need of using `.getCollection()`):

```
db.myCollection.find({...})
```

In the case of querying, it's not possible to have a query with a "mask" for a nested document key using dot notation, since you need a pointer to the right field, before accessing the embedded document. From your example, a better document structure is actually an array of documents, with numbers as their IDs, as:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("598842f22605c6cb8de9db78"),
  "nested":[
    {
      "_id": "17", "name" : "some name 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "18", "name" : "some name 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "19", "name" : "some name 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

With this, you can query it using dot notation as well, but if you don't know the ID, you can do (for instance):

```
db.myCollection.find({"nested._id": {$gt: "17"}})
// This will return all documents in the collection myCollection that has at least one nested document in its nested array with _id greater than "17"
```

Instead, if you would want to return just the nested documents, you can do projections on the document return, like (using the structure from the question):

```
db.myCollection.find({"17.name": "some name 1"}, {"_id": 0, "18":0, "19": 0}) //= {"17" : { "name" : "some name 1" } }
//This will find a document with nested "17" (the key for a nested document) that has name as "some name 1", but projecting only the "17" document
```

If you need to use just the nested documents and don't care about the document which does the nesting, the better structure here is to put these "17", "18" and "19" in a different collection, using these numbers as IDs. See [dot notation documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but changing data structures is out of the question unfortunately. I wasn't using mongo shell, using JS instead. I suppose I should've told that in question. I guess I will just have to use recursive loops...

Comment: Yeah, looping is a possibility, since you have to go on that path. As I stated before, you really have to get a pointer of the field to access it. Hope, at least, that I've clarified some issues for you :)